# Create EC2 instance, start instance and run Linux command using Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am trying to create an AWS EC2 instance, start it, execute a simple Linux command and print the output. However, I keep getting:

> botocore.errorfactory.InvalidInstanceId: An error occurred
> (InvalidInstanceId) when calling the SendCommand operation: Instances
> [[the_instance_id]] not in a valid state for account <some_account>

At the moment I use this boto3 script to create the instance:

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

instance = ec2.create_instances(
        ImageId='ami-0b828c1c5ac3f13ee',
        MinCount=1,
        MaxCount=1,
        InstanceType='t2.micro'
)

print(instance)
```

In the AWS Console the 'status check' says '2/2 checks passed'. I then copy-paste the instance-id in to the below script to execute a Linux `echo` command:

```
import boto3
commands = [' echo "hello world"']
ssm_client = boto3.client('ssm')

output = ssm_client.send_command(
InstanceIds=[<the_instance_id>],
DocumentName='AWS-RunShellScript',
Parameters={
    'commands': commands
    }
)

print(output)
```

However, I get:

```
botocore.errorfactory.InvalidInstanceId: An error occurred (InvalidInstanceId) when calling the SendCommand operation: Instances [[<the instance id>]] not in a valid state for account <some account>
```

Comment: Did you do all the steps in [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-setting-up-ec2.html)?  The ec2 instance has to have permissions to register with ssm.  You do this by attaching an iam role to the instance. The guide will explain.

Comment: I have terminated it now but it was in `2/2 checks passed` when I ran the second script. Do I have to wait longer before running that script?

Comment: I'm not sure your ubuntu image is already configured to have ssm agent running or not.  spin one up by hand, experiment logging in with the web console.  once you can do that , the instance is registered with ssm and what you're doing should work

Comment: @erik258 I've just followed the page you linked to. Do I need to use the role name anywhere, or once i've created the role, I can repeat my scripts above? (assuming Ubuntu does have SSM running)

Comment: I'm going to use the Amazon Linux image for now.

Comment: I like amazon linux, well suited for their environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you send this command, you need to check few things.

First, the AWS SSM (Systems Manager) agent needs to be running on the instance. Without it, you won't be able to send commands through SSM. Fortunately, AWS Linux distro has it installed by default, so choose this AMI to keep things easy. But if you want to use Ubuntu or other stuff, you need to start AWS SSM Agent first and make sure it's always running.

The second thing is instance permission. You need to add to the Instance role policy called `AmazonSSMManagedEC2InstanceDefaultPolicy`, or other applicable. Here is a full list that describes your potential use cases: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/security-iam-awsmanpol.html

Then you should be able to easily run SSM commands and connect through AWS Web console terminal :-)

Comment: After creating it, do I need to add `AmazonSSMManagedEC2InstanceDefaultPolicy` via boto3 when I create the instance?

Comment: @rare77 `AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore` is much strict than the one I proposed. It should work completely fine, so you can definitely start from the Core one. Anyway, if you face any issues, you can easily extend instance permissions to the policy of my proposal - if you see positive results, then you'll start looking for the least permissive policy of your use case.

Comment: @rare77 Yes, the policy needs to be assigned when you create the instance. So in your case - it will be through boto3.

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand why every example I find of `create_instances()` completely forgets to mention this. Are they circumnavigating it?

Comment: I think so. SDK examples are always showing only basic use cases. They can't be as much detailed as possible, because they would end up with an endless list of examples.

Comment: Think i've found one. Need to pass `IamInstanceProfile={ 'Name': 'ExampleInstanceProfile' }` in to `create_instances()`

Comment: Great :-) The instance profile needs to be created separately, using different method:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam/client/create_instance_profile.html

It returns IAM role name created for the instance. Then, you need to assign to this role a managed policy using another method: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam/client/attach_role_policy.html

The policy ARN of SSM Core can be hardcoded, as it's the same for everyone.

Comment: So I created the role using these instructions https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-setting-up-ec2.html and I simply passed the name of the role in to `create_instances()`. This seems to have worked, so I am unsure what the additional part you describe in your last comment is?

Comment: I believe your role already had the policy applied :-) In case you want to automate all the things, you would need to follow the additional part.